What shape do the overlapping blades of a mechanical aperture take in 3D space?
Camera apertures typically consist of a number of thin overlapping blades mounted in a circle, each with a fixed hinge near the outer edge, and a mechanism to rotate the blades about their hinges to change the size of the central hole.

Consider an aperture made of $n$ identical and equally spaced blades of thickness $h$ with hinges located some distance $r$ from the aperture's center, where $n ∈ ℕ$, $2 < n$, and $0 < h ≪ r$. Is it possible to determine the actual 3D shape/curvature of the blades mathematically?
I know the blades cannot be perfectly planar, because planes cannot be overlapped in a circle without intersecting. Other than that, I don't know how to approach this question. I'm not even sure if the shape changes or remains fixed as the aperture opens and closes.
